# ClickOnce publish location change still looks for old location

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, iis, clickonce

We have a prototype application that was originally published to an external server hosted on AWS (for discussions sake assume this was on http://prototypes.mysever.com/MyApp/).

The prototype size started to mount up so for speed we moved it to an internal server (assume http://internal/MyApp/).

I did some clearing out of our IIS server that was hosting the original published app (external) and removed the application. Now if we try to install a copy of the app, it fails, because it wants to talk to the original server even though we published it elsewhere (for like 80+ versions).

In the .application file I noticed a reference to the old server, but changing this didn't solve our problems.

Is there a way to stop it looking for the old server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry,

I deleted my last answer, because I misunderstood the question.  Yes, there is a way to change the update location.

1. Open the Project properties page, and go to the Publish tab.
2. Click the Updates... button.
3. On the updates screen, verify that the update location is pointing to the new location.

[image]

Comment: This is confusing... The updates work fine when being published to the new location. This (to me) seems to be if you want to update from a different location to where the version was published to not the original publish location. Can anyone confirm this setting?